# Matplotlib dpi is ignored

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

This is not a duplicate question .I have processed image that I get after performing some OpenCV functions.I want to save that file with 1000 dpi but it's not working

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
plt.rcParams['savefig.dpi'] = 1000


#Then after some processing

mask = plt.read(mask)
plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(mask,cmap='gray')


plt.savefig('D:/newapproach/T&Oplt.jpg',dpi=1000,bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

The file get saved with 96 dpi not matter what I specify as dpi

Comment: Which [backend](http://matplotlib.org/api/index_backend_api.html) are you using, and does it support the `dpi` setting? Also, `plt.show()` may always be 96 dpi, but the file it saves may not. Is the file not the specified resolution?

Comment: did you mean database ? by that I am not using one .I am developing something which stores intermediate images before the out and for ocr to be accurate dpi should be minimum 300 and there is no work around for adjusting dpi if this works the image from this will have the desired dpi I need

Comment: Nope, I meant exactly what I wrote. Matplotlib has different backends for generating files, listed in the link I provided beginning with `matplotlib.backend.`. Also, calling `plt.show()` doesn't display the file - it generates a new plot. If you want to inspect the file, you'll have to view it using other means (e.g. opening it using Windows Explorer).

Comment: Here's the [Matplotlib backend documentation](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend)

Comment: @SeanLake I looked into the properties of the file TX)plt.jpg in windows it showed 96 dpi instead of the dpi which I set

Comment: Try `png` and then convert to `jpg` using something else. I've successfully set resolution on `png` files before.

Comment: Qt5Agg is the output of plt.get_backend()

Comment: Also, try switching to straight `agg` - you can't use `plt.show()`, but it's the backend I've successfully changed dpi on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154378/discussion-between-sachin-divakar-and-sean-lake).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code from the question runs fine. You may verify by simply looking at the width and height in pixels, this should be in the range of ~4000 if you did not change the figure size (not known from the code above).

Note that even though everything is working as expected, some image viewers and also the properties dialog of the Operating system may show 96dpi. That is mainly because dpi is not actually a sensible figure for pixel images. Pixel images are simply defined by the number of pixels and by nature do not have something like dpi associated with them.

An option you may have is to use PIL to open the saved image and save it again, directly specifying the dpi:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mask = np.random.rand(30,30)
plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(mask,cmap='gray')

plt.savefig('figure.jpg',dpi=300,bbox_inches='tight')

from  PIL import Image
im = Image.open('figure.jpg')
im.save('figure.jpg',dpi=[300,300])

plt.show()
```

Comment: I am using sunny page to do OCR train for tesseract .It always says the image is not 300 dpi .and hence its not detecting text even after 99.% of noise is cleared http://answers.opencv.org/question/174209/tesseract-not-detecting/ this is my problem

Comment: I updated the answer with a possible solution. Note that the problem of doing ocr is a completely different one, for which you may ask a completely new question.

Comment: I found the same and worked it out anyway thanks for it bro.Thanks for the effort and time you spent on it and you are earnest